# Automatically run shell script on boot (autostart)

Tags: shell, driver, boot, raspberry-pi2, spi

I'm facing with a "little" problem. I have created a script that starts a program which uses the SPI port. If I run this script manually it starts without any problem. BUT if I try to start it with startx in the Raspberry Pi the Pi will fails to open SPI port and it throws an error. Whats more I can't open SPI port later manually.

Does anyone have idea how to solve this problem? The scripts has to run continuously, so I think the Pi try to load the driver after startx, but my program running so it fails. It is also ok if it would start after everything loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If none login will be done, uses the [init.d](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/04/get-to-know-linux-the-etcinitd-directory/) to start is at boot. But if someone (and just one) will login the Pi, you could start the script from the `$HOME/.profile`. [Here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/40730/130945) some guide about executing scripts automatically.

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately it still not works. I have tried to run from this script in the "foreground" and in the background (with the & sign) and in both case it show the same "errors".  It "said": unable to connect to SPI0.0. I have waited 60 seconds after boot (with a sleep) so I really don't know what is the problem. Maybe simply the raspberry Pi is not for such kind of "sophisticated" things.

Comment: For sure the PI can do this. As been a hardware port maybe you really need some more "sophisticated" way. You already have used the `init.d` right? Something like [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20357/how-can-i-make-a-script-in-etc-init-d-start-at-boot). Not able to use the port after the script tries to load by itself means that the script got the access to the hardware, but some permission/confirmation/pass is missing, but "unable to connect" can be the wrong address or missing admin rights.

Comment: I don not run the script with sudo, but I neither run the program normally. The script does not loads the driver, I hoped the os will do it automatically (The script waits for 120 seconds after start). If I would know how to load the driver manually from script it would be great, may you have any idea? Finally yes I have already tried it with init.d.